# Updating Image in SQL (Delphi 7)

Tags: sql, delphi

Using the Parameters in a Query, I can store and retreive imagaes to and from a MySQL database.
I do this, like :

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'Insert into TABLE (ID,PICTURE) Values (:ID, :PICTURE)';
Query.Parameters[0].Value := '1';
Query.Parameters[1].Assign(Picture);
Query.ExecSQL;
```

In this case Picture is a TImage.

Now, I would like to change the image in the table by a new image.

I can't find a way to do this like I did above.
Something like :

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE TABLE SET (ID,PICTURE) Values (:ID, :PICTURE)';
Query.Parameters[0].Value := '1';
Query.Parameters[1].Assign(NEWPicture);
Query.ExecSQL;
```

Is there a way to do this like so? Or does somebody knows an other way ?

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be something like:

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE TABLE SET PICTURE = :PICTURE WHERE ID = :ID';
```

Obviously your parameters would then be switched around with the blob being [0] and the ID being [1].